# Can scripts write/read directly to/from Google Document?

Tags: javascript, gwt, google-apps-script, google-apps

I want to create a script that would do the followings:

- create a form
- once a user fill the form and submit, the script would copy a
  previously created Google Document "template" and fill out the fields
  the copied template with the information submitted.

Now I am aware that you can **not** create scripts within the "Document" container (only Spreadsheet and Sites), but can a standalone Google Apps Script read or write directly to Document like the way it could with Spreadsheet?

I read somewhere that Google Apps Script can **not** read text from a Google Document, but only text and CSV. Is that still true with the recently update to Google Apps Script?

Comment: After further research, I got a better understand of the Google Apps Scripts platform. Even though Document is not a container for Scripts like Spreadsheet/Sites, you could manipulate documents using Document services (like the answers below indicated). Since Drive was introduced, Scripts can now be created from Drive (without creating Spreadsheet/Sites).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done.  The easiest example to follow is [Employee of the Week example](https://drive.google.com/previewtemplate?id=0AhvDA0t7m3SkdGJFZkgwSlptcklyUUQ2NzNXeC1fbkE&mode=public#).  This takes in user input , merges it into a doc and automatically emails the result out to the user, which you can remove if you like.   There also a [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdoDuZfP6a0).  Should get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [DocumentApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_documentapp).